# How do I assign additional ExraFiles using Pipes to have more than one output stream?

Tags: go, pipe, io-redirection

I have a command to which I send data through Stdin and expect 28 output streams (including `Stdout`).

So I wanted to use the `cmd.ExtraFiles` field with an `os.Pipe` for each of the `os.ExtraFiles`.

I wrote the following:

```
backgroundContext, cancelCommand := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
cmd := exec.CommandContext(backgroundContext, "command", args...)
cmd.ExtraFiles = make([]*io.File, 27, 0)

var outputPipe io.ReadCloser
var inputPipe io.WriteCloser

outputPipe, inputPipe, err = os.Pipe()
cmd.ExtraFiles[0] = &inputPipe
cmd.ExtraFiles[1] = &outputPipe
```

The last two lines generate an error since the types do not match:

```
./main.go:876:26: cannot use &inputPipe (type *io.WriteCloser) as type *os.File in assignment
./main.go:877:26: cannot use &outputPipe (type *io.ReadCloser) as type *os.File in assignment
```

I'm sure we can assign pipes since I can for example use the `StdoutPipe()` function and it works as expected.

How am I supposed to do that with the `os.ExtraFiles`?

Comment: It appears like ExtraFiles are handles that the child process inherits, so it needs files, not pipes. Maybe 27 named pipes work? They would have handles, and you open them with os.OpenFile.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Would Stdout be a named Pipe? In C I could just use file descriptors... Hmmm...

Comment: stdout is not a named pipe. You don't need to pass stdout to the child process.  The ExtraFiles will cause the handles for those files to be inherited by the child process. Is that really what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question does not compile because the `*os.File` values returned from os.Pipe are stored in variables with interfaces types `io.ReadCloser` and `io.WriteCloser`.  Pointers to  values with these types are not assignable to an `*os.File`.

Fix by assigning the return values to variables with type `*os.File`.

```
cmd.ExtraFiles = make([]*os.File, 27)
outputPipe, inputPipe, err := os.Pipe()
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
cmd.ExtraFiles[0] = inputPipe
cmd.ExtraFiles[1] = outputPipe
```

Bonus fixes:

- It's `os.File`, not `io.File`.
- Allocate the slice with length and capacity of 27. It's an error to allocate a slice with capacity less than length.

Comment: Ah! Great! It's the other way around. I need the `outputPipe` for saving the output of my command to an S3 but was wondering why neither the in nor out would work as an extra file. This compiles. Now to debug that thing!